# X.org universal graphics driver?

Tags: architecture, x86, x86-64, xorg, vesa

I'm trying to build a minimal live distribution with the smallest x.org possible. I've found http://privatebox.org/?doc/Xorg-Minimal-HOWTO - which suggests that I only include one graphics driver (obviously the graphics driver for the intended laptop/desktop) , anyway .. is there such thing as a universal graphics driver? I'm not looking for crisp lines or 3D performance, just something that is fairly standard and will work on most hardware?

I'm also looking to build a single distribution (not a separate one for x86-64). Am I correct in thinking that Vesa will not work if I try and run the distribution on an x86-64 machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [VESA](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.0/doc/html/vesa.4.html) driver is probably what you are looking for. But note that performance, even for 2D operations such as window blitting, will be very poor.

Comment: Yes, you can reasonably expect any x86 and x86-64 computer to understand VESA.